# How to define a python constant from a string key

Tags: python, configuration, constants

I have a module with constants define in its `__init__.py`. I would like to read in a config file and define constants based on those config contents. Is there a way to define constants from string keys, like this:

`__init__py`:

```
config = { "FOO": "BAR" }
for key, value in config.items():
    define(key, value) # <- "define" is what I am looking for
```

`foo.py`:

```
from . import FOO
print(FOO)
> BAR
```

I also considered a Config class object that has those constants, but then I would always have to access them via the object; not as neat as simply writing the constant in my code.

Or is there any other more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that, you should create the variable in your module, but as you know the variable name only on run-time, you will have to use `setattr` on your module (Which you can access from the `sys` module):

```
import sys

setattr(sys.modules[__name__], var_name, var_val)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Both answers work. I ended up using this one, since it is _a little_ more obvious what the code does, e.g. set an attribute on *the module* to make it able to be imported.

Answer (score 2):

You could add them to [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins):

```
import builtins

config = { "FOO": "BAR" }
for key, value in config.items():
    # I prefer to have them prefixed, to make sure not overwriting existing values!
    setattr(builtins, 'cfg_%s' % key, value)

# available everywhere (other modules as well)
print(cfg_FOO)
```

Out:

```
BAR
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `builtins`, never even was aware of them so far.